# How to test a median survival time to a theoretical value in R?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I want to test for my survival object the median of survfit.
so i can do the median test so that when i test to alpha=5%, i calculate the 95% CI for the median and evaluate if the null hypothesis value is in the CI:
Here the 95% CI for the median goes from 2.21 to 2.94. The null hypothesis value of 3 is not included-> the test is significant at alpha=5% significance level.
i have done this as a plot but i need a function that can do this test.
how can i test as a function in R this hypothesis that
H_0: median > median0=3 vs. H_1: median>= median_1=4

**Edit**:
I have a single arm population (N=233) for which I would like to know if the median progression free survival (PFS) is significantly different from 3 months. for this I need a function to test this. how can I make this functin? so that I can simulate accordingly

thanks for any idea or small help

```
#testing the hypothese: H0: M <median_0 vs. M >= median_1 

lambda0=0.2310491
lambda1=0.1732868
median_0=3
median_1=4
accr.time=6
follow.up=12
total.time=accr.time + follow.up
n.size=233
set.seed(12345)
St=rexp(n.size,rate = lambda0)     
u=runif(n.size,0,accr.time)        
dta=data.frame(pmin(St, total.time - u), as.numeric(St < total.time - u))
names(dta)=c("pfs","cens")
dta.survfit <-survfit(Surv(pfs,cens)~1,conf.int=0.95,conf.type="arcsin",data=dta)
dta.survfit
plot(dta.survfit,conf.int = TRUE,conf.type = "arcsin",xlab = "time",ylab =  "survival")
abline(v=c(summary(dta.survfit)$table[c("0.95LCL","0.95UCL")],summary(dta.survfit)$table["median"]), col=c("blue","red","green"), lwd=0.5)
abline(h=0.5,lwd=1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X3wB.png)

Comment: If a falue falls outside a CI it corresponds to rejection in a two-sided test, not a one-sided test.

Comment: i only test for single arm study therefore one sided test @user2554330

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i would like to know how can i test the median? i know that normally i can test from CI but i need a function to do that not only from plot so i can simulate afterwards. because i am doing design for single arm study and want to test the power and alpha for median PFS by simulation. thanks @Community